# Unicode RSS issue in android

Tags: java, android, xml, unicode, rss

I'm using this code to display RSS in Unicode (Arabic) text but the result is shown as :

```
&#x644;&#x642;&#x627;&#x621; &#x645;&#x646;&#x633;&#x642;&#x649; &#x627;&#x644;&#x645;&#x647;&#x631;&#x62c;&#x627;&#x646;
```

While the real text is

> لقاء منسقى المهرجان

my code :

```
public void getDataFromFeed(){

    try {
        Feed = new URL(URLFeed);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = db.parse(new InputSource(Feed.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        title = new String[nodeList.getLength()];
        pubDate = new String[nodeList.getLength()];
        link = new String[nodeList.getLength()];

        for(int i=0;i<nodeList.getLength();i++){
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;

            NodeList titleList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("title");
            Element titleElement = (Element) titleList.item(0);
            titleList = titleElement.getChildNodes();
            title[i] = ((Node) titleList.item(0)).getNodeValue();


            NodeList pubDateList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("pubDate");
            Element pubDateElement = (Element) pubDateList.item(0);
            pubDateList = pubDateElement.getChildNodes();
            pubDate[i] = ((Node) pubDateList.item(0)).getNodeValue();


            NodeList linkList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("link");
            Element linkElement = (Element) linkList.item(0);
            linkList = linkElement.getChildNodes();
            link[i] = ((Node) linkList.item(0)).getNodeValue();

        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I tried `getTextcontet()` method which gave me the same result.

Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the proble  of ecoding encode your url with URLEncoder.encode.... for an example
 URLEncoder.encode(Url, "UTF-8")